# Show progress dialog while the called non-activity class gets executed

Tags: android, progressdialog

I don't know where i am going wrong.
I have some data online which is synced offline on request, for this i have made an non activity class like this:

```
public class RefreshSqlite {

Context context;
private static final String TAG = "REFRESHSQLITE";

private SessionManager session;
private SQLiteHandler db;
HashMap<String, String> sessionuser;

private String  tag_json_arry = "login_req";


public RefreshSqlite(Context context)
{
    this.context = context;
    session = new SessionManager(context);
    sessionuser = session.getUserDetails();
    db = new SQLiteHandler(context);
    db.refreshuser();
    setclasses();
}

private void setclasses() {
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Const.URL_GET_CLASSES, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            try {
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response.toString());
                for (int i=0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                   //method to store data
                }
                setperiod();  // IS ANOTHER VOLLEY REQUEST 
            }
            catch (JSONException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            Toast.makeText(context, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            hideProgressDialog();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams()
        {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            \\PARAMETERS ENTERED
            return params;
        }
    };
    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_arry);

}
```

As you can see, i am calling another request in this volley request. Similarly other requests are called, and it takes a while (Indeterminate) to complete.

here is the method in my activity using which i call this class.

```
public class Homepageactivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_homepageactivity);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getApplicationContext());
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    //onclickevent
      { 
        new refreshdata.execute();
      }

 }
private class refreshdata extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... arg0) {


        new RefreshSqliteteachers(getApplicationContext());

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {

        pDialog.dismiss();


        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Now everything is working fine, class gets called, data gets refreshed. But the only problem is that i am not able to show progress dialog, which would restrict the user while the data loads.
Sorry for such a long question, i did try to make it as short as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Change the code block from this:

```
//onclickevent
  { 
    new refreshdata();
  }
```

To this:

```
//onclickevent
  { 
    new refreshdata().execute();
  }
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: hey, sorry for the mistake, i might have done that while checking for different answers. i updated the code, and did try your solution but it still doesn't show the dialog. The app just hangs and if clicked somewhere, a android dialog appears asking if i wish to close or wait for the app to respond.

Comment: @RishabhLashkari Can you please use `Homepageactivity.this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`